# I cannot validate this blank HTML page to XHTML 5.1

Tags: html, xhtml

I cannot validate this blank page to XHTML 5.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>XHTML 5.1 blank page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Blank page</h1>
    <p>Text here.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

All tags are well-closed and I specific the DOCTYPE, what I'm wrong?

Comment: *cannot validate*?

Comment: What tool are you using? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Quentin, I'm using Total Validator.

Comment: … and what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need requires that the attribute indicated should be used. *xmlns*
And you should look this if you sse the 'lang' or 'xml:lang' attribute to denote the language of the document.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thanks, Tony! :-)